# How can i obtain the actions of an attached policy in AWS using SDK V3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, policy, identity-management

I've been having problems for days looking for a way to get the actions from the attached policies. I need to list the actions that a permission set has. Now I'm using SDK V3 with javascript. Could someone guide me on how to get them?

I have tried with various functions of the IAM client and the SSO Admin client but without any success to date..

Comment: Retrieve the policies e.g. using GetRolePolicyCommand and then parse the JSON policy.

Comment: Hello! Maybe I have expressed myself badly. The requirement that they asked me is the following: list the actions of the attached policies which are native to AWS. I am not referring to policies created for users or roles but to the policies created by AWS

Comment: AWS managed policies such as [AdministratorAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess)? To retrieve a managed policy document that is attached to a role, use GetPolicy to determine the policy's default version, then use GetPolicyVersion to retrieve the policy document. If you want a third-party, maintained dump of all AWS managed policies then see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/55b358748be3c314f956).